# Injecting service singleton instance to another service without constructor

Tags: angular

I have:

- **BaseService** that would be used as parent class
- **UtilService** is used for utility functions
- **AService** is child class of BaseService (AService extends from BaseService)
- **BService** is also child class of BaseService

I want to inject **UtilService** singleton instance to **BaseService** but ***without*** using constructor ( constructor(baseService: BaseService){} ) because if not, both **AService** and **BService** need to pass **UtilService** singleton instance as argument when calling **UtilService**'s constructor ( super(arguments) ) which is obviously a redundant step.
So I want to know if there is any another way to do this without passing **UtilService** singleton instance in **AService/BService** constructor's super call.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will be singelton, but you can inject a service using

```
constructor(private inj: Injector) { }
....where you need..
const customService= this.inj.get(CustomService)
```

Comment: Although I added UtilService in module providers, I still got this error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for UtilService

Comment: You add the UitlService in module providers in app.module.ts? Your UtilService is like @Injectable() export class UtilsService ?